# `static`, `extern`, `const` in header file

Tags: c++

```
//a.h

extern int x1;
static int x2;
int x3;
static const int x4;

class A {
    public:
        static const int x5 = 10;
};
```

`a.h` will be included by multiple `.cpp` files, my question is:

1.`x1` is just a declaration, isn't it? So its definition should be done in one of those `.cpp` files, right?

2.`x2` is a definition, right? I used to think that `static int` is also a declaration just like `extern int`, but I was wrong. `x2` will only be visible in `a.h`?

3.`x3` will be defined multiple times if `a.h` is included in multiple `.cpp` files, so `x3` will result in compile-error, right?

4.`x4` is a definition, right?

5.Here in class A, `x5` is a declaration, yes. But what about `x4`?

Comment: What do you mean by the question in item 5?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I mean why `x5` is a declaration but `x4`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1.x1 is just a declaration, isn't it? So its definition should be done in one of those .cpp files, right?

Correct

> 2.x2 is a definition, right? I used to think that static int is also a declaration just like extern int, but I was wrong. x2 will only be visible in a.h?

A different `x2` will be available in each translation unit that includes the header.

> 3.x3 will be defined multiple times if a.h is included in multiple .cpp files, so x3 will result in compile-error, right?

More precisely it will result in a linker error. The compiler processes each translation unit, the linker binds them together and detects that the symbol is defined multiple times.

> 4.x4 is a definition, right?

Yes, it is a definition, but as with `x2` each translation unit will have it's own `x4` (both because of `static` and because it is `const` which implies *internal linkage*

> 5.Here in class A, x5 is a declaration, yes. But what about x4?

Yes, `x5` is a declaration only (with initialization). The confusion might arise because the keyword `static` is reused to mean different things in different contexts. In `x5` it means *attribute of the class*, while in `x4` it means *internal linkage*

This last case is special. It is the only declaration (IIRC) where the declaration can have a value, and the reason is that it allows the compiler to *use* the value of the constant in all translation units that include that header as a *compile time constant*. If the value had to be provided with the definition, then only a single translation unit would have access to that value. The definition of that static member would be:

```
const int A::x5; // no initialization here
```

And you must provide one if the member is *odr-used*. Now the fact is that in most cases the constant will not be *odr-used* as the compiler will substitute the value when the expression `A::x5` is used. Only when the member is used as an *lvalue* you need the definition, for example:

```
void f( const int & ) {}
int main() {
   f( A::x5 );
}
```

Because the argument to `f` is a reference, the use of `A::x5` requires an *lvalue* (note, const-ness and lvalue/rvalue-ness are almost orthogonal), and that requires the definition of the member in a single translation unit in your program.

Comment: @Alcott: The symbol cannot be accessed from outside of the translation unit in which it is defined. This implies that if multiple translation units define a symbol by the same name with internal linkage, each translation unit will get their own different symbol (i.e. different symbols even if they have the same name).

Answer (score 4):

1. correct
2. It is a definition, `x2` will be 0, and every translation unit that contains the header will have its own copy of `x2`.
3. Yes, but it will result in a linker-error, not compiler.
4. Same as 2., but you can't modify it.
5. Inside a class, `static` has a different meaning. It's legal there just because `x5` is of const integral type which is also initialized.

Comment: So `x2` is not a global var which can be shared between multiple `.cpp` files?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: In a single translation unit you define it as `const int A::x5;` (no initialization allowed in the definition). If you want to verify that this is not a definition add to the program: `void f( const int & ) {} int main() { f( A::x5 ); }` and you will get a linker error (until you add the definition).

Comment: @Alcott no, x2 will be different for every `cpp` file.