# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`static`, `extern`, `const` in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908151/static-extern-const-in-header-file)

I am working in Visual C++ and having this error.

I have declared below two extern lines in global.h seperately.

```
extern CSocketManager  m_SocketManager[10];
extern CSocketManager* m_pCurServer;
```

```
1>ServerSocketDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CSocketManager *                      m_pCurServer" (?m_pCurServer@@3PAVCSocketManager@@A)

1>SocketManager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CSocketManager * m_pCurServer" (?m_pCurServer@@3PAVCSocketManager@@A)
```

Does anyone have an idea what might cause these errors?

Comment: externs have to be defined somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908151/static-extern-const-in-header-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects declared in the .h as extern also have to be declared in a .cpp file.

The problem is that linker doesn't know where to find the two objects.

Solution: you also have to declare m_pCurServer in the .cpp file because it's the .cpp that is being compiled, not the header.

Comment: In other words, the `extern` keyword says "this thing I'm describing here exists somewhere, trust me!". If it doesn't actually exist somewhere and you try to use it, the linker will give you the errors you're receiving.